# Results page works in IE only

Tags: c#, javascript, web-config

I have a results page only working in IE.  It is developed using C# and js in visual studio.  So I select a search parameter from the drop down list and search.  The results from the DB are displayed in a results page.  Those results seem to only be displayed when I use IE. Chrome and fireFox allow for everything else to work except the results:/

Any ideas what could be occurring? Something i need to check with my web.config perhaps?

Thank you in advance=)

C

Comment: Post some code we can't tell you what you did wrong if we don't know what you did.

Comment: Can you post some code? Most times these issues are related to unsupported CSS or javascript functions.

Comment: Cross-browser compatibility is an ongoing hazard in web development.  Are you doing any funky CSS or Javascript to generate the UI?  Those are the two things browsers tend to handle the *most* differently when it comes to how to render html.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an html issue and unrelated to ASP.NET. You should examine the generated HTML. It will be especially easy to see if the data is in the DOM by using Chrome and Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome (since it's a place where it's not working) bring up the page and press CTRL+SHIFT+I - this will bring up the DEVELOPER TOOLS. Once up, attempt to use the page and watch the CONSOLE tab of the developer tools. You most likely have scripting errors and the Console will point them out. Many times, you can even click on the console-report to go directly to the offending code (but sometimes you cannot). Regardless, the developer console should help you find the trouble.

If it's a CSS issue, the first tab will be the most helpful to you instead - you can find the generated code in HTML and click on it, then all CSS styles will be on the right and you can review them (and even change them if you need to for testing purposes) to find and eliminate trouble items.